# What do you say "to achieve more than the goal"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Given some goals on a project, what should I use to say I achieved that and a lot more than what was expected.

Answer (score 3):

My goal was **surpassed** by a substantial margin.

> - [**surpass**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/surpass) - tr.v. sur·passed, sur·pass·ing, sur·pass·es
>
>   1. To do more than or be superior to: surpassed her classmates in academic honors. See Synonyms at excel.
>   2. To be beyond the limit, powers, or capacity of; transcend: misery that surpasses comprehension.
>   3. **To be greater than, as in degree or quality; exceed:** The cost of the project surpassed its budget projections.

From the web

- When that goal was surpassed last year, officials quickly began ...
- In the end, that goal was surpassed by over one-third.
- The 2009 goal was surpassed several months in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could say you went [*above and beyond*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/above%20and%20beyond).